# How do I "call" css code on a link click?

Tags: css, web, css-transitions

I have this code that after a certain time frame it triggers a transition. I use this by assigning the body in the html a class either .transition, or .transition1.

However, there are pages where I would like the user to be able to look at for as long as possible. So when they are done I'd like if they could click a link to the next page but before it moves to use a transition.

How could I go about this?

Here's my CSS

```
.transition{
    animation: transitionIn 5s 10s;
}

.transition1{
    animation: transitionOut 5s 10s;
}

@keyframes transitionIn{
    from{
        background-color: #106560;
        opacity:1;
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    to{
        background-color: #ffffff;
        opacity:1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

}

@keyframes transitionOut{
    from{
        background-color: white;
        opacity:1;
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    to{
        background-color: #106560;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

}



@keyframes fadeInUp {
    from{
      opacity: 0;
  
    }
    to{
      opacity:1;
      transform: translateY(0);
  
    }
  
}

@keyframes fadeInOut{
    from{
      opacity:1;
  
    }
    to{
      opacity:0;
      transform:translateY(-10);
    }
}
```

I tried using .transition:active but this didn't work, not that I thought that it would.

Comment: You might want to show your JS for us to see how the classes `transition` and `transition1` are being applied initially.

Comment: @Kalabasa, I don't have any JS. I am using pure CSS and HTML.

Answer (score -1):

if you need user change page , u wanna show new page with animation .

you need Javascript for check location address page ,

then if location page '/about' this for smapel , main parent about page take

class in your external css like animateAboute , and this class get your animation in css ,

i hope this help

but you can use libray like framer motion

https://www.framer.com/motion/